# Hadoop mapreduce - mapping NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to write a simple map-reduce program that , given as input a directed graph represented as a list of edges, produces the same graph where each edge (x,y) with x>y is replaced by (y,x) and there are no repetitions of edges in the output graph.

```
INPUT
1;3 
2;1 
0;1 
3;1 
2;0 
1;1 
2;1

OUTPUT
1;3 
1;2 
0;1 
0;2 
1;1
```

This is the code :

```
public class ExamGraph {



    // mapper class
    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, NullWritable> {

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            value = new Text( value.toString());
            String[] campi = value.toString().split(";"); 
            if (Integer.getInteger(campi[0]) > Integer.getInteger(campi[1]))
                context.write(new Text(campi[1]+";"+campi[0]), NullWritable.get());
            else context.write(new Text(campi[0]+";"+campi[1]), NullWritable.get());
        }

}

// reducer class
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable <NullWritable> values , Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // create new job
    Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration());

    // job is based on jar containing this class
    job.setJarByClass(ExamGraph.class);

    // for logging purposes
    job.setJobName("ExamGraph");

    // set input path in HDFS
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

    // set output path in HDFS (destination must not exist)
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    // set mapper and reducer classes
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    // An InputFormat for plain text files.
    // Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used
    // to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and values
    // are the line of text.
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    // set type of output keys and values for both mappers and reducers
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    // start job
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
}
```

When I run the jar file using :

```
hadoop jar path/jar JOBNAME /inputlocation /outputlocation
```

I got this error :

```
    18/05/22 02:13:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1526979627085_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ExamGraph$MyMapper.map(ExamGraph.java:38)
    at ExamGraph$MyMapper.map(ExamGraph.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

But I did not find the error in the code.

Comment: Which line is giving you the exception?

Comment: Line 38 , but I find in this moment the error , it was my fault ; I confused the getInteger() with the parseInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem , I confused the method `getInteger()` with the `parseInt()` in the mapper.